# Добавление нового ssh-ключа

Tags: ssh, ssh-key

С помощью команды

```
ssh-add my-key
```

добавляю `ssh`-ключ. Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored.

В чём проблема?

Comment: Вбиваем в переводчик Google и вуаля! Получаем ответ на вопрос: "Требуется, чтобы ваши файлы закрытого ключа НЕ были доступны другим лицам. Этот закрытый ключ будет проигнорирован."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключи должны быть доступны для чтения только вам:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/my-key
```

Если вам необходимо сделать ключи доступными для чтения и записи:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/my-key
```